# How to add one more entry in selection field of an already defined odoo model using inheritance

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

**Environment :-** Odoo 9, Python 2.7

**Module A**

```py
from openerp import models, fields, api, _, exceptions

class Games(models.Model):
    _name = 'moduleA.games'

    game = fields.Selection([
       ('cricket', 'Cricket'),
       ('hockey', 'Hockey'),
       ('golf', 'Golf')], 
       string='Game', default='cricket', required=True
    )
```

**Module B**

```py
from openerp import models, fields, api, _, exceptions

class ExtraGames(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'moduleA.games'

    def __init__(self, pool, cr):
        res = super(ExtraGames,self)._columns # res = {}
        super(ExtraGames,self)._columns['game'].selection.append(
            ('chess', 'Chess')
        )
```

Now using that code, I want to add one more game Chess inside already defined games list but its not working. Actually I am getting empty dictionary ( {} ) as result of super(ExtraGames,self)._columns and because of that its giving **KeyError 'game'**.

How can we do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`selection_add`](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.fields.Selection):

```py
from openerp import fields, models

class ExtraGames(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'moduleA.games'

    game = fields.Selection(
        selection_add=[('chess', 'Chess')],
    )
```